# Issue in executing webservices

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws

I am working with webservices in java, when i use client to call my services in am getting java.lang.outOfMemoryError. My web services client would be flex code, Error Message in detail shown below

```
12:14:00,879 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[localhost].
[/SQLAppWeb].[SQLMobileAppWebServices]] Servlet.service() for servlet SQLMobileAppWebServices threw exception: 
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.output.Encoded.ensureSize(Encoded.java:61)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a wealth of information on the web about dealing with `OutOfMemoryError`s. See for example ["Java Performance Tuning"](http://www.javaperformancetuning.com/news/qotm036.shtml), or the [Java Glossary at mindprod.com](http://mindprod.com/jgloss/runerrormessages.html#OUTOFMEMORYERROR). I suspect several [relevant SO questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=java%20outofmemoryerror) were suggested as you were typing your own, as well. If you have a specific problem, then be more specific in your question. Otherwise, this is about as much help as anyone will be able to give.